# How to target an input box in a tr while changing another dom elment in same row?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get text value of a text box while changing other dom element in the same tr by this , but never worked. How can we accomplish this ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="drcr" type="text" /><td>
    <td><input class="jvamt"  name="parrot" type="text" /><td> 
  </tr>     
</table>    

<script>
  $(".drcr").change(function(){
    var thisval = $(this).parents("tr").children(".jvamt").text();
    alert(thisval);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. No td in your tr

Comment: Also... tables are for displaying data not for page layout

Comment: html errors are edited , following @LelioFaieta suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your logic which are causing the issue

- your HTML is invalid as you're missing the `td` around the `input` elements
- when you add the `td` you'll need to use `find()` as the `input` are not children of the `tr`.
- you need to use `val()` to get the input's value

With those fixes, it works fine:

```js
$(".drcr").change(function() {
  var thisval = $(this).closest("tr").find(".jvamt").val();
  console.log(thisval);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="drcr" type="text" />
      <input class="jvamt" name="parrot" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```